# PHP external API access fails, when called from another page on same domain?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony, cors

I'm trying to do a little cross-site scripting with Jquery and PHP/Symfony (`HttpFoundation` Component), but I can't get the server to return necessary data.

My goal is for JQuery to retrieve JSON from the local domain: PHP accessing an external API, server-side.  I have opened up the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to `*` to allow CORS ok, and everything works fine directly with dummy data.  Using the JSON endpoint via JQuery fails, however.  Everything happens on the same domain.

So, this dummy JSON data renders fine, if I manually create a JSON response:

```
$data = json_decode('{
        "foo": "bar",
        "items": [
            {
                "id": "1234",
                "foo": "bar",
                "baz": "bingo",
            },
            {
                "id": "4567",
                "foo": "blork",
                "baz": "fladdurk",
            }
    }', true);

$response = JsonResponse::create($data, 200);
$response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
$response->send();
```

The JSON shows up nice in my client at `http://localhost/json_endpoint?q=stuff`.  I get back a nice JSON string:

```
{"foo":"bar","items":[{"id":"1234","foo":"bar","baz":"bingo"},{"id":"4567","foo":"blork","baz":"fladdurk"}]}
```

This works perfectly fine using JQuery on the front-end, as well.  The dummy data appears exactly the same, and I can work with it; presumably Symfony doesn't mind supplying the JSON when it's not from an external API.

Things start to get weird if I try a PHP request to an external API (which is where the data is supposed to come from):

```
protected function url_tools__request($url, $timeout=10, $headers=array()) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); //suppress output.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    $ch_exec = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $ch_exec;
}

$url = "http://api.example.com/?q=more+stuff";
$headers = array("Accept:application/json");

$xsr = $this->url_tools__request($url, 10, $headers);
$data = [
    "foo" => "bar",

    // here's the rub
    "items" => json_decode($xsr, true),
];

$response = JsonResponse::create($data, 200);
$response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
$response->send();
```

With this live data, everything appears correctly in the client if accessed directly at `http://localhost/json_endpoint?q=stuff`. So the API is working fine. I get the exact same full JSON string as above:

```
{"foo":"bar","items":[{"id":"1234","foo":"bar","baz":"bingo"},{"id":"4567","foo":"blork","baz":"fladdurk"}]}
```

But if I attempt to access this endpoint via JQuery AJAX (perhaps at `http://localhost/another_page.html`), I get back a JSON string without any "items":

```
{"foo":"bar","items":[]}
```

My JQuery code looks like this:

```
xhr = $.ajax({
    url: '/json_endpoint',
    data: {q: "more+stuff"},
    type: "GET",
    dataType : "json"
})
.done(function(data, textStatus, request) {
    console.log(data)
}
```

I have looked at my requests and responses from all angles, and the string resolved by PHP/Symfony is the same whether using dummy or actual (XSS) data.  I'm pretty sure there's not a race condition or anything.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not a solution, but my next step would be to try putting the `url_tools__request` call and data assignment in a `try ... catch` and just echo out the error message to be sure there's not one being thrown (or log if you have a logger to hand).  Then, I'd probably var_dump/log the `$xsr` as well before trying to decode it and seeing what that produces on an ajax request.  Nothing's jumping out though.  Then perhaps start adding some more try catches elsewhere.  Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks.  Yeah, I'm new to PHP, and debugging isn't coming naturally to me yet.  Appreciated.

Comment: Yeah, better practices are definitely available for walking through the code (see [xdebug](http://www.phptherightway.com/#xdebug) and [exceptions](http://www.phptherightway.com/#exceptions)) than what I've suggested there [in case any other readers don't know].  Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out the CORS stuff was totally a red herring.

JQuery was encoding the URLs with percent signs, which my PHP wasn't accounting for.  I interpreted the failed call as something wrong with CORS; this was not the case.

So this url would actually work:

```
$url = "http://api.example.com/?q=stuff";
```

The trouble was with more complex URLs, with spaces and punctuation.  This would work OK when accessed directly:

```
$url = "http://api.example.com/?q=more+stuff";
```

But when using JQuery, it decided to turn the query string into:

```
more%sBstuff
```

...which was confusing PHP.  So higher up in my code, where before I had this:

```
$url = urlencode($request->get('q'));
```

now I had to add another urldecode

```
$query = urlencode(urldecode($request->get('q')));
```

Sorry about the confusion.  I hope this helps somebody someday in internet land.